# How to get inner id/class from div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have something like this:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

this is the html. Inside of the container, I add other `div` elements using jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get("/Ask", {}, function (response, status) {
        $.each(response.cars, function (index, val) {
            $("#container").append("<div class = 'q' id=" + val.id + "\">" + val.carName + "<br>" + val.date + "</div>");
        });
    });

    $("div").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
    });
});
```

On click, I want to retrieve the id from my inner divs (they are 1, 2, 3) but whenever I click on any of the divs added using jQuery, it shows `container` or nothing at all. How can I get the id from the recently added divs? Tried even with:

```
$(".q").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this...

```
$( "#container" ).on( "click", ".q", function() {
  alert($(this).attr("id"))
});
```

Comment: yes, it did the job. Thank you!